# Parameterizing superclass method and non-parameterized (concrete type) method in subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, parameterized-types

I have an abstract superclass `ValueType` and two non-abstract subclasses `IntType` and `DoubleType`. How can define types in the superclass method like following

```
public abstract class ValueType {
    public abstract <T extends ValueType> T add(T other);
}
```

that I allows to write concrete types (e.g. `public IntType add(IntType other)` or `DoubleType add(DoubleType other)`) in subclass method

```
public class IntType extends ValueType {

private int val;

public IntType(int val){
    this.val = val;
}

public int getVal(){
    return this.val;
}

@Override
public IntType add(IntType other) {
    return new IntType(this.val + other.getVal());
}
```

```
public class DoubleType extends ValueType {

private double val;

public DoubleType(double val){
    this.val = val;
}

public double getVal(){
    return this.val;
}

@Override
public DoubleType add(DoubleType other) {
    return new DoubleType(this.val + other.getVal());
}
```

In the above example, the subclass method does not override the superclass method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the abstract class generic itself, not only its method.

Elevate the generic type `<T extends ValueType>` as a class generic parameter. Note with this action the class `ValueType` becomes also generic, therefore `<T extends ValueType<T>>` takes the place to avoid raw types:

```
public abstract class ValueType<T extends ValueType<T>> {
    public abstract T add(T other);
}
```

Then the concrete child class extends from a generic class and is forced to override the abstract method (private fields, getters and setters omitted):

```
public class IntType extends ValueType<IntType> {

    @Override
    public IntType add(IntType other) {
        return new IntType(this.val + other.getVal());
    }
}

public class DoubleType extends ValueType<DoubleType> {

    @Override
    public DoubleType add(DoubleType other) {
        return new DoubleType(this.val + other.getVal());
    }
}
```

By the way, you have two typos:

- `return new IntType(this.value + other.getVal());` should use `this.val`.
- `return new DoubleType(this.value + other.getVal());` should use `this.val` as well.